# Installing dependencies for an XNA game: Where is the XNA Framework registry path?

Tags: installation, xna, registry, nsis

How do I make an NSIS installer check if the user has the XNA and .NET frameworks installed, and install them if they aren't? (I'd rather not have it add extra prompt boxes appear, only have a page informing the user that I am making the installation).

EDIT: Due to no answer, I'll just ask this:
Where is the XNA Framework in the Registry? Microsoft claims it is at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\XNA\Framework
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb464156(XNAGameStudio.40).aspx )

But I went to that path through regedit (in Windows 7), and it was not there. There was, however, an XNA folder at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\XNA\
But not the /Framework directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Windows 7 64bit?
If so you may be looking into wrong registry key.
See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system

There is special conversion for keys in 64bit Windows, for example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node
```

is the 32-bit equivalent of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software
```

(although 32-bit applications are not aware of this redirection).

Comment: Thanks! I found this out by chance (Yes.. I started looking in every registry folder that I didn't know its purpose...) some time later and forgot to post it, but this answer is great for anyone who is also confused by this.

Answer (score 3):

The registry entries you are looking for are:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\XNA\Framework\v4.0 (32-bit)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\XNA\Framework\v4.0 (64-bit)
```

On my Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit machine both those checks return true.

I just finished writing an NSIS install program, here is the script I used for installing the XNA portion:

```
Section "XNA Framework 4.0" XNA
    #check 32bit
    ReadRegDWORD $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\XNA\Framework\v4.0" "Installed"
    #check 64bit
    ReadRegDWORD $1 HKLM "Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\XNA\Framework\v4.0" "Installed"    
    DetailPrint "32 bit XNA:"
  DetailPrint "  $0"
    DetailPrint "64 bit XNA:"
  DetailPrint "  $1"
  File "xnafx40_redist.msi"
    ${If} $0 != 1 
    ${AndIf} $1 != 1
        #they do not have framework 4 installed
        ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$INSTDIR\xnafx40_redist.msi"  /passive'
    ${EndIf}
    Delete /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\xnafx40_redist.msi"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

In NSIS you should use `SetRegView 64` when reading the 64bit/native registry so you don't have to deal with Wow6432Node...